# How did Anna pay for the goods at Wandering Oaken's Trading Post (and sauna)?

Tags: frozen

When Anna runs off to talk to Elsa she doesn't seem to have time to even dress appropriately for the cold, much less pack supplies and money just in case she needs to pick up something along the way. As the story unfolds it turns out that she does end up needing to shop for supplies along the way. Fortunately she encounter's Wandering Oaken's Trading Post (and sauna).

As you can see when Kristoff wants to purchase some items Oaken is upfront with the price for the goods.  Due to Kristoff's rudness he is thrown out of the store. Next Oaken asks Anna if she wants more than the clothes and the boots. Anna hesitates and the scene cuts.

**Do we know anything about how Anna acquires the goods from Oaken's store?** I don't think she pulled "I don't need to pay because I'm the princess card" because Oaken only refers to Anna as "dear-y" so it isn't clear he knows she's the princess. Given that he threw Kristoff out for rude behavior I don't think Oaken would blindly accept Anna's claim that she should get free stuff based on her word that she's a princess. Furthermore it doesn't make sense to me that Anna had a bunch of money squirreled away in her dress somewhere when she went to the ball. Why would she carry cash when there is literally nothing to spend her money on.. The only other alternatives I can think of would be maybe Anna traded her fancy ball gown and slippers for the goods, or Oaken recognized her clothing as clothing of a noble so allowed her to take the goods on credit.  While either of those options, or another, could conceivably work I'd like to know if this is addressed in any of the extended Disney works.

I'm willing to accept anything from kids books to references in [*Once Upon a Time*](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time), or basically anything else Disney had a hand in creating. Of course fan fiction type sources aren't legit.

---

In the movie *Frozen Fever* Oaken is seen giving Elsa a cold remedy of his own invention. By this time he clearly knows who both sisters are so the cold remedy could be a gift or added to the girls tab so I don't think this is necessarily relevant to Oaken's initial encounter with Anna.

Comment: There's nothing in the junior novel, the script nor the "art of" book that explains it.

Comment: There's also nothing in the Little Golden Junior Book of the Film, Essential Guide to Frozen, Frozen Read-Along Storybook, Frozen Graphic Novel tie-in nor in the Anna's Icy Adventure Reader.

Comment: There's nothing in The Frozen Heart, nor anything useful in the Official movie colouring book (which I'll admit was a bit of a long-shot).

Comment: @Valorum holy crap man! It's moments like these that remind me why you're the Jon Skeet of this stack....  Also for the record there's nothing in *Frozen 5-Minute Bedtime Stories* either.

Comment: In the Big Golden Novelisation she says that she "bought" them, So we know at least that she didn't just command him to hand the goods over.

Comment: @Valorum ooh! That's a start at least...

Comment: I suspect a start and an end. The scene appears in a bunch of different books, but never with an explanation.

Comment: FWIW, if Oaken insisted on collateral, Anna's necklace would be a more likely choice than the gown and/or slippers.  After the cut, we can't see whether she's still wearing it or not.

Comment: @HarryJohnston That's true. The necklace could also be collateral. Anna is seen with a big bag full of stuff after Kristoff sings so she could have put the necklace/clothes in there too.

Comment: It seems to me for most of history it was rather easy in more civilized lands to tell someone's rank and status from their clothing.  Anna is wearing a ball gown from a ball at the royal palace.  If she tells Oaken to request repayment in Anna's name at the palace there is a strong probability that Oaken will trust her.

Comment: @Erik - Patience is a virtue.

Answer (score 6):

Anna gave Wandering Oaken **her coronation dress** in exchange for the goods.

---

He has it on sale in *[Once Upon a Snowman](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt13061790/)*.

[image]

Note that the dress isn't being sold with the necklace which, presumably, she's still in possession of. He also, evidently, sold her a similar looking bodice to the one she was wearing previously.

Answer (score 4):

When Anna first arrives at Oaken's, she is wearing a necklace with a large stone. The necklace is gone when she leaves the trading post, so maybe she was able to trade it along with her finer clothes.

Comment: Certainly another possibility to add to the list. However, as the original poster is asking for confirmation of what happened between her and Oaken that allowed her to make her purchase, this doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: I agree with @RDFozz. This is just one of the many possibilities. Anna could have traded the necklace or she could still have it underneath the winter cloak/dress, or she could have the necklace in the bundle she carried. I'd like an official source saying how she got the goods from Oaken, not just reasonable speculation. This was also mentioned in [the comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172322/how-did-anna-pay-for-the-goods-at-wandering-oakens-trading-post-and-sauna/181602#comment462515_172322) as a possibility earlier.

Comment: I've downvoted. You don't see her neck in any later scene which means there's no proof that this was the method of payment, nor that it was gone. It might be under her coat or in a pocket